# Hosting GWT WebApp

Tags: tomcat, gwt, hosting

Just asking for some recommendations. I looking for good hosting alternatives for a GWT webapp. Google AppEngine is a problem due to FatTable limitiation for the DB. Planning to run hibernate Postgres/MySql. One host that I've found offers 100MB for the JVM which seems very little. They offer Tomcat6.

I'm looking for some guiding numbers when it comes to memory for not getting out of memory problems. Anyone have any good tips?

Superthanks in advance!

Niclas

Comment: As an aside, to use GWT, you don't have to use Java on the server. Just an FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT is a client side technology, so anywhere which can server static files will do.

If you then need to add server side code which connects to a db and sends dynamic data to the client side, then there's lots to choose from.  Fasthosts, Rackspace, Storm Internet in the UK are ones I've used in the past and are ok.

As JP notes, you can use any server side technology to send data to the client side.